# I can't use animateTo in my ViewMode to open and close my bottomSheetl it show it is internal to ModalBottomSheetState

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

This is the BottomSheetEvent Class that the event extends from

sealed class BottomSheetEvent{

```
data class OpenBottomSheet<T> @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class) constructor(
    val state:ModalBottomSheetState,
    val scope:CoroutineScope,
    val bottomSheetType:String,
    val bottomSheetData:T?
    ):BottomSheetEvent<T>()

data class CloseBottomSheet @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class) constructor(
    val state: ModalBottomSheetState,
    val scope:CoroutineScope
):BottomSheetEvent<Nothing>()
```

}

The viewModel code here animateTo underlines red when hover around it shows animateTo is internal to ModalBottomSheetState

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)

```
fun onBottomSheetEvent(event: BottomSheetEvent<*>){

    when(event){
        is BottomSheetEvent.OpenBottomSheet<*> ->{

            event.scope.launch {
               //sheetScaffoldState.show()
                event.state.animateTo(ModalBottomSheetValue.Expanded)
            }

            viewModelScope.launch {
                _bottomSheetContent.value = event.bottomSheetType
                _botttomSheetData.value = event.bottomSheetData
            }
        }

        is BottomSheetEvent.CloseBottomSheet ->{
            event.scope.launch{
               event.state.animateTo(ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden)
            }

        }
    }
}
```